# Add listener to editor (Eclipse RCP)

Tags: eclipse, editor, eclipse-rcp

I have created a simple editor for an xml file, in which I have a tree and a couple of buttons to add and remove elements in the tree, similar to the editor of the web.xml file in web projects:

[image]

What I want to do is, every time I add node in the tree I need to create a folder in the project, likewise, every time I remove a node from the tree I need to remove the folder I have created before when I added the node. Is there a way to listen for this type of changes in the editor?

Comment: What sort of tree? A SWT `Tree` or a JFace `TreeViewer` or ...?

Comment: I would think about it the other way around: have the tree be a representation of the folders that updates automatically as folders come and go. The buttons would manipulate the folders, not the tree. That's the MVC way, where the model is the project folders.

Comment: It's a JFace `TreeViewer`